# Validating model values does not throw an exception

Tags: php, kohana

I got a problem with validating models in Kohana ORM, it should throw an ORM_Validation_Exception, however, it does not. I am trying to validate an emailaddress.

Model_Emailaddress

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        'emailaddress' => array(
            array(
                'Valid::email'
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Controller_Test

```
public function action_valid()
    {
        $email = ORM::factory('emailaddress');

        $email->emailaddress = 'test';

        try
        {
            $email->create();

        }
        catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
        {
            echo Debug::dump($e->errors());
        }
    }
```

This example should dump an array with errors to the screen but instead it just saves the emailaddress without further notices.

When I change 'Valid::email' to 'not_empty', it does throw an exception. After some debugging I discovered that Valid::email returns false, as it should.

EDIT: As some people stated, changing 'Valid::email' to 'email' does not help. Also, when I place an exit inside the email method, the script execution will be stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some heavy, heavy debugging I discovered that the Kohana validation class contains a bug in combination with php 5.3.3. It should work, but it doesn't.

In Kohana_Validation::check()

Change

```
$data[$field] = Arr::get($this, $field);
```

To

```
$data[$field] = Arr::get($this->_data, $field);
```

In Kohana_Validation::errors()

Change

```
':value' => Arr::get($this, $field),
```

To

```
':value' => Arr::get($this->_data, $field),
```

Answer (score 0):

oop..  how about just usage:

```
 'email' insert  'Valid::email'
```

better usage save() method:)